# Filling bar colours with the mean of another continuous variable in ggplot2 histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataset at the municipality level. I would like to draw a histogram of a given variable and, at the same time, fill the bars with another continuous variable (using a color gradient). This is because I believe the municipalities with low values of the variable I am plotting the histogram for have very different population size (on average) when comparing with the municipalities that are in the upper end of the distribution.

Using the `mtcar` data, say I would like to plot the distribution of `mpg` and fill the bars with a continuous color to represent the mean of the variable `wt` for each of the histogram bars. I typed the code below but I don't know how to actually make the `fill` option take the average of `wt`. I would want a legend to show up with a color gradient so as to inform if the mean value of `wt` for each histogram bar is low-medium-high in relative terms.

```
  mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, fill=wt)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a genuine histogram you need to transform your data to do this by summarizing it first, and plot with `geom_col` rather than `geom_histogram`. The base R function `hist` will help you here to generate the breaks and midpoints:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg = cut(x      = mpg, 
                   breaks = hist(mpg, breaks = 0:4 * 10, plot = FALSE)$breaks,
                   labels = hist(mpg, breaks = 0:4 * 10, plot = FALSE)$mids)) %>%
  group_by(mpg) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), wt = mean(wt)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(mpg)), y = n, fill = wt)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 40), name = "mpg") +
  geom_col(width = 10) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, using the hist() function to get the breaks and labels was very creative!

Comment: Awesome! This is exactely what I was looking for. Last question: how can I define the labels showing up on the x-axis? Say I want it to show from 0 to 40, with a gap interval od 10?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a histogram exactly, but was the closest that I could think for your problem

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  #Create breaks for mpg, where this sequence is just an example
  mutate(mpg_cut = cut(mpg,seq(10,35,5))) %>% 
  #Count and mean of wt by mpg_cut
  group_by(mpg_cut) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    wt = mean(wt)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg_cut, fill=wt)) +
  #Bar plot 
  geom_col(aes(y = n), width = 1)
```

[image]